# Android Studio returns "Could not find play-services-ads.aar"

Tags: java, android

I want to build my project, but everytime I try this error is shown in console:

> Could not find play-services-ads.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1).
>   Searched in the following locations:
>      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/12.0.1/play-services-ads-12.0.1.aar

but in my build.gradle I've just found this:

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.0'

so I dont know whats the problem here.
I also searched with the *Find in Path..* for *12.0.1* but I found nothing containing this.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Please post your gradle files.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue. Try to move the Google Maven Repo declaration to the top of **all** lists of repository declarations in your project. Don't forget the `allProjects` tag in your project level build.gradle.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google() // or maven{ url "https://maven.google.com/" }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: @Andi Ashani, did my answer solve your problem? If so, could you please accept it?